Cannot import SVG file into React project
Can someone tell me how to import an GVS image into a React project? I created the project using parcel and not create-react-app.
I tried exporting as a component using ReactComponent and also installed the svg plugin for parcel, but still I could not import the SVG image.

You can create a function that returns your image in separate file and then import it to your app file (or any other file where you want to use it);
If you code using JSX it should look something like this:
MyImage.js
const MyImage = () => {
   return (
      <img scr='./path/to/my/image.svg' alt='My Image'/>
   )
}

export default MyImage;

App.js
import MyImage from './MyImage.js';

function App () {
   return (
   <>
    <MyImage/>
   </>
   )
}

export default App;

